# Merge multiple text files into one, with alternating lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have managed to merge two text files together using this code

```
    For Each foundFile As String In
        My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("path")
        foundFile = foundFile
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("path", foundFile, True)
    Next
    extraline = vbCrLf
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("path", extraline, True)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("path", extraline, True)
    For Each foundFile2 As String In
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("path")
        foundFile2 = foundFile2
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("path", foundFile2, True)
    Next
```

It merges them however I would like it to merge the two text files one line at a time. for example

Textdoc1 contains

```
First Line
Third Line
```

Textdoc2 contains

```
Second Line
Fourth Line
```

I would like the output file to contain:

```
First line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

any help is very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of ReadAllText. Here's a quick example to show you how it could work (I haven't tested this code, it's just for reference)

```
Dim linesFromFile1() As String
Dim linesFromFile2() As String
Dim combinedLines As New List(Of String)  

linesFromFile1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file1")
linesFromFile2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file2")

For linePos As Integer = 0 To System.Math.Max(linesFromFile1.Length, linesFromFile2.Length) - 1
    If linePos < linesFromFile1.Length Then combinedLines.Add(linesFromFile1(linePos))
    If linePos < linesFromFile2.Length Then combinedLines.Add(linesFromFile2(linePos))
    Next

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("file3", combinedLines.ToArray())
```

If you have very large file, then I suggest you look into using [StreadReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. This way you can [read a line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without loading everything at once.